# How do I specify the controller in the async object using HTML only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am getting started with Kendo UI and trying to use the uploader in async mode and I don't see any documentation on what fields are available in this async object.

```
    <div style="width: 350px">
        <input name="files[]" id="files" type="file" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#files").kendoUpload({
                async: {
                    saveUrl: "save",
                    removeUrl: "remove",
                    autoUpload: true
                    //controllerName? Where is the documentation for this?
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If I were to use the MVC extensions, the razor syntax has a field to specify the controller name. Where do I put that if I am not using MVC extensions/razor syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option to specify the Action or the Controller. You could only specify the full URL to the saveUrl option. As a work-around you can use the [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper the MVC provides:

```
async: {
                saveUrl: "save",
                removeUrl: '@Url.Action("ActionName","Controller")',
                autoUpload: true
            }
```